# create a webinar registration in WordPress on submit send ICS file event to the calendar to save

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

i was trying to create a form on Contact form 7, but i want at the end of the registration to get an email from the website with ICS file event to save the event link of the webinar meeting in the calendar once the form submitted,

what is the best solution for that functionality on wordpress,

Thanks,

i tried to create a form on contact form 7 plugin but i didnt get the functionality to send ICS event to save it in the calendar